# How to use #locale in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

How do I get the correct value for my locale in a Map object?

**map**

```
"greeting": {
    "en_US": "Hi"
   , "ko_KR": "Hello"
}
```

I've done this, but it 's too bad.

```
$ {greeting.get (__${#locale} __)}
```

Comment: Is the locale that you want to look up the current locale?

Comment: Also, do you have a map as a property of another object?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

The thought is that you're not iterating through the values of the map correctly.  The following can give you some direction on how you can do it, assuming you are adding an attribute called `greeting` to your model.  It appears that you have a map as a property of another object, and I will assume it's a `List`.  I will also assume that you're trying to use the current locale.

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${greeting}">

    <th:block th:each="map : ${item}">

        <th:block th:text="${#strings.equals(#locale, map.key) ? map.value : ''}">Value</th:block>

    </th:block>

</th:block>
```

You can test with this sample server-side code:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(2);

    map.put("en_US", "Hi");
    map.put("ko_KR", "Hello");

    List container = new ArrayList(1);
    container.add(map);
    model.addAttribute("greeting", container);
```

Please note that if you are using Spring, you will instead want to use `messages.properties` for each locale for internationalization.  It will make your life much easier and will better follow conventions from Spring.